# How do I make Banshee re-scan for cover art?

Tags: banshee

I restored my banshee db as per [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/8572/how-do-i-backup-my-banshee-listening-history). My music and listening history shows up as expected, but the cover art is missing, and Banshee won't scan for it. "Rescan music library" doesn't check for cover art. Neither does disabling/re-enabling the cover art plugin. I can't find an option to do this--is it possible?

Comment: I had a similar problem that I fixed by deleting my Banshee db and starting again. Not an ideal solution I know!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The covers are stored in ~/.cache/media-art/
You might try renaming the folder to force Banshee downloading the covers again. 
I haven't tested the solution, so don't delete the folder alltogether.

Comment: This doesn't technically answer the question in the title, but it did solve my problem. My solution was to backup `~/.cache/media-art/` as well as `~/.config/banshee-1/banshee.db`.

Answer (score 11):

Try typing in a terminal:

```
banshee --fetch-artwork
```

This will make banshee download missing covers.

Comment: Worked great! Banshee loaded all the embedded cover art in a few minutes after this command!

Answer (score 2):

Banshee stores album covers in `~/.cache/media-art`. If you copy that folder along with the others, the covers should all be waiting for you when you open up Banshee.