# Moving banshee to a new PC

Tags: mount, music, banshee

I have searched and found a few answers on this topic but they do not answer my question:

- [Moving Banshee music to another computer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/176120/moving-banshee-music-to-another-computer)
- [How do I backup my Banshee listening history?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/8572/how-do-i-backup-my-banshee-listening-history)
- [How do I export banshee library settings to another machine?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/79656/how-do-i-export-banshee-library-settings-to-another-machine)

I have just got an SSD HDD and have performed a totally fresh ubuntu install. I am manually transferring the settings of programs I want. I have been saving metadata to files but this is insufficient as it has not worked for all album art and has not saved scores and "date added" paramters used in banshee.

I have copied banshee-1 into the new install, and banshee now loads with all the files, scores, "date added" and playlists etc but:

My music is mounted at `/media/sda2/guy/Music` on the old install and this is where banshee is looking for it, but this location is now called
`/media/pc-user/0391a5db-61d8-4c3d-b633-59c710ed4386/guy/Music`

How can I fix this? I tried renaming the mount point in "Disks" but this gives a mount error for sda2 on boot.

Additionally, with the files not found as they are, banshee is not displaying album art - is it not stored in banshee-1?

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

I had the same issue and found [this article](https://cybolic.wordpress.com/2010/04/08/fixing-a-banshee-music-database/) that solved my problem.

Quoting:

> So, long story short, to change the location of your music files in
>   the Banshee database, here’s what you do (close Banshee first):
>
> ```
> sudo aptitude install sqlitebrowser
> sqlitebrowser ~/.config/banshee-1/banshee.db
> ```
>
> Now change to the tab labelled “Execute SQL” and write something like
>   the following:
>
> ```
> update CoreTracks set Uri = replace(Uri, '/home/<olduser>', '/home/<newuser>');
> update PodcastEnclosures set LocalPath = replace(LocalPath, '/home/<olduser>', '/home/<newuser>');
> ```
>
> You are now done and can start Banshee again :)

Then i copied my album art from `~/.cache/media-art`